# How to calculate DS:[0040207A] manually?

Tags: assembly, x86

[image]

[image]

How to get the result `77D507EA` manually from `DS:[0040207A]` according to register info above?
**UPDATE**

[image: memory map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your using OllyDbg, so to make it a little relavent to your situation:

`DS` indicates that it(the address) is in the data segment, `[0040207A]` is the address in the data segment. if you goto (crtl + g in olly) address 0x40207A, you'll see some bytes, this is the pointer to `MessageBoxA`. just note that your missing the size of element pointed to by the address (in this case its `DWORD PTR`), the full instruction should be `MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[0040207A]`

In the data dump(window in the bottom left), it should look something like: `0040207A    EA 07 D5 77`

In the CPU window, it might get properly analysed by olly(depends on the plugins and confings), in which case it'll look something like: `0040207A MessageBoxA    EA 07 D5 77 User32.MessageBoxA`

Also not, the address `0040207A` might not be static, so going there will olly in a different session might not work, due to windows rebasing the virtualized binary

**Update**

It would appear that both your assembly knowledge and knowledge of x86 architecture is really poor, as such I would recommend that you read up on these subjects, [wikipedia is a good start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language), else your not going to understand how addressing and pointers are handled on an assembly level

Comment: `0040207A = base_of_DS + 0040207A`,but how can I see `base_of_DS` in the first place?

Comment: @COMer: "base of DS" is defined in the PE of the image your examining, and it only applies to the image your exaiming. under olly you can use memory map(crtl-M iirc) to view the various memory mapped sections, `.data` is the Data Segment(just note though, thats not really true, 'DS:' can be used on anything, its just an accessing/addressing mode). you'll do well to give the art of assembly a read(its free these days)

Comment: The base of DS should be `77D507EA-0040207A=7794E770`,but I've checked the memory map(see my updated post),there is no such address :(

Comment: @COMer: no, `77D507EA` is a kernel function address, it has nothing to do with this, other than the fact its stored at `0040207A`. have a look at the segment registers section here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture `DS:` indications that it'll be data(it a hint, it can be ignore, data can be read from a code segment too). in your image the data segement(as set by the linker) starts at `0402000`, so you really have: `0402000` + `7A` = `0040207A`.